# Loading Image is not showing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, loading, busy-cursor

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdtBank" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <div style="text-align:center;">
    <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdtBank" id="updateProgress" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/ajax-loader.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." style="padding: 10px;position:fixed;top:45%;left:50%;" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    //My Code is Here
</div>
```

> I have copy above code from the tutorial and stackoverflow answers,
>   but image is not showing at all. Kindly help me i cant find my mistake

Comment: move `UpdateProgress` outside of `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Is Your Page Take Time To load DATA...??

Comment: No it doesn't take long time

Comment: then it will not shown this update progress....Update Progress used when page take time for specific process which indicate to user that some process is running...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decreasing the time after which the `ProgressTemplate` is displayed. By default this is 5 seconds.
This behaviour is controlled by the Property: [**`DisplayAfter`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.displayafter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Specify the number of milliseconds to elapse before showing the progress control, i.e 2000 if you wish to wait for 2 seconds

```
<asp:UpdateProgress DisplayAfter="2000" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdtBank"
     id="updateProgress" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Put your `asp:UpdateProgress` out side to the `asp:UpdatePanel`** - as below .

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdtBank" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
    <div style="text-align:center;">

    //My Code is Here
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel >

 <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdtBank" id="updateProgress" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/ajax-loader.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." style="padding: 10px;position:fixed;top:45%;left:50%;" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```